# How to remove an item from a listbox and a list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I wanted to delete a selected item from the listbox, and after that, to remove the object which was referenced to that item I wanted to remove. I tried the following

```
private void Remove_candidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = candidate_list.SelectedIndex; // candidate_list is the ListBox
            if (candidate_list.SelectedItems.Count > 0) candidate_list.Items.Remove(candidate_list.SelectedItem);
            candidates.RemoveAt(i); //candidates is the object list
        }
```

When I start the application, it crushes after clicking on the "Remove" button.

Comment: Your problem is in using "int i = candidate_list.SelectedIndex"; SelectedIndex could be "-1" when no items are selected; when many items are selected SelectedIndex is not a good solution as well

Comment: For the selected index I need to do this int i = candidate_list.SelectedIndices; or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
if (candidate_list.SelectedItems.Count > 0) candidate_list.Items.RemoveAt(i);
```

More robust way of doing this

```
int i = candidate_list.SelectedIndex; // candidate_list is the ListBox
if (i >= 0) 
{
    candidate_list.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    candidates.RemoveAt(i); //candidates is the object list
}
```

Comment: what was the problem in my solution exactly?

Comment: Hard to say without tracing it but using the index is always preferred.  That code is not very robust - is there ever going to be a case where the user can click remove without selecting an item, depsite there being items in the list?

Comment: Okay, I will try it again in few hours, and I will inform you about what happens :)

Answer (score 1):

In *general* case, when *many* items can be selected you can use
this code to remove *all the selected items*:

```
  // To prevent candidate_list repainting while items updating
  candidate_list.BeginUpdate();

  try {
    // When using RemoveAt() one should use backward loop 
    for (int i = candidate_list.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      int index = candidate_list.SelectedIndices[i];

      candidate_list.Items.RemoveAt(index);
      candidates.RemoveAt(index); 
    }
  }
  finally {
    candidate_list.EndUpdate();
  }
```

Comment: So I should just do the same, only without a for loop. I will try that later, and I will inform you about any further progress :)

Comment: @TheAdnan: if you're going to eliminate the for loop, pay attention to the case when no items are selected

Comment: the index in that case is -1 or 0?

Comment: candidate_list.SelectedIndex == -1; candidate_list.SelectedIndices.Count == 0